# Insert a logo before a link in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, position

I would like to add an image before the a tag.

```html
<a href="index.html">Apple</a>
```

So for example add an Apple Logo before, but in the same line of Apple text.

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: It would best to show what you have tried before posting the question here.

Comment: @Dvorog Yes, you right. But it was too wrong my code :). Next time! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `display:flex;` to `warp div` to set the `a` and `img` in same line**
You can set `align-items: center;` to center text
Learn about `flex`:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

```css
    .warp{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    }
    img{
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="warp">
<img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg"/>

    <a href="index.html">Apple</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Really thanks! There's just a little problem: using the the a tag don't recognize my class.

Comment: Sure! Here we go.

Comment: color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    padding: 0 1.25rem;
    text-decoration: none;

Comment: do you set class to a `<a class="className">` and then in css `.className{..your style}` ???

Comment: Before was so <a class="logo" href="index.html">Apple</a>

Comment: And Apple was white

Comment: you dont see the apple text because background is white and also the color of text that the reason why i set color:red in fiddle...

Comment: Removing <div style="display:flex;align-items: center"> the link it's white, like should be.

Comment: Find the problem!

Comment: #header > .logo {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    padding: 0 1.25rem;
    text-decoration: none; }
  #header > nav > a {
    color: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0.75rem;
    text-decoration: none; }

Comment: Should I remove display: inline-block, don't I?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172839/discussion-between---and-andrea-p).

Answer (score 1):

Use the image tag for inserting the logo. Properly adjust the width and height of logo

Try this:

```
<img src="url" width="30", height="30">  <a href="index.html">Apple</a>
```

Here, provide the appropriate url for the logo.

Comment: I tried something like that but the link moves right lofting a lot of scape, maybe margins?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to dynamically insert the image, look at this example:
to check :

http://grpd.es/apple/apple.html

http://grpd.es/apple/tomato.html

code example :

```
<html>
<BODY>
<a href="index.html">Apple</a>
<a href="peach.html">Peach</a>
<a href="tomato.html">Tomato</a>
<button onclick="insertar()">imagen</button>
<script language="javascript">
function insertar(){
imagen=document.createElement('img');
imagen.src="apple.png";
imagen.id="img1";
document.body.appendChild(imagen);
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(i=0;i<el.length;i++){
if(el[i].innerHTML=='Apple'){
var iimagen = document.body.insertBefore(imagen,el[i]);
}
}
}
</script>

</BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: for more efficient work you need create elements with id example: <a href='index' id='uno'>Apple</a> this help you to seek to element with next : var uno=document.getElementByID('uno') .... you refer to element with uno example uno.addeventlintener(click,....